# Nodejs debugging - auto generation of error message

Tags: node.js, debugging, testing, optimization, error-handling

I am new to nodejs (async) debugging. I would appreciate some help regarding error messages -

```
var l, m, opiton= {};
// option has actually been mis-spelt here as opiton

..... 
// some more code

option.name= "new name";
```

Now, at the point of assignment: `option.name= "new name";` 
nodejs server freezes without any indication, that it has encountered an error.

It would be great if nodejs could "auto generate" an error message, and say - 
`undefined object "option" in line 5178` or something similar.

Figuring out that `option` was actually mis-spelt as `opiton` takes a lot of time, especially in a large code base, with multiple callbacks per request. And it would be great, if that time can be saved.

Question - Is there a generic solution for locating run-time errors in nodejs servers? 
 
(In a large server code base, adding a ton of logging is useful for running analytics in production environment, but not the most optimum solution for a test environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an uncaught error handler:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('UncaughtException: message: ' + err.message);
  console.log('UncaughtException: stack: ' + err.stack);
});
```

I would be very hesitant to use this pattern in production code since at this point the program is in an unknown state. It's best to exit at this point and (potentially) restart.

Comment: Saw, that in my code, I was sending the log to a text file, and had totally forgotten about it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem vjj! The very worst thing is when you get an error you cannot track down.